# How to change dropdownlist to textbox and viceversa based on another dropdownlist

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing an application where I am using `country` (dropdown list) and `state` (dropdown list).

The question is when 1 select `country`, it's states will be populated in `state` dropdownlist but the state list is only provided for USA and other countries are not provided so they have to type in.

So how to change `state` input type (TEXTBOX OR DROPDOWNLIST) based on USA (`country`). 
That is

```
If USA -DROPDOWNLIST Else Other Countries -TEXTBOX
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make is a select box by default, then use this jQuery to alter it.

```
if($(#country_select).val() != 'USA'){
  $('#selectbox').attr('type', 'textbox');
  $('#selectbox option').remove();
}
```

**NOTE**

This is a very simple solution, and requires that the default value is USA. I think there is enough info there to build a more robust solution.

Comment: If you want your solution to degrade beautifully you should rely on minimum requirements (text box usable for everyone) and pimp it through javascript to get the dropdown menu

Comment: You're probably right (no, you're definitely right) but I though the above script was just enough to point someone in the right direction, hence the note.

Answer (score 0):

Hi ON the country drop down list attach an event onchange and switch over the selectedValue if it is one of the countries isnt have a city hide the drop down list and show the textbox and vise versa .

```
<select id="country" onchange="check(this)">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="EG">EG</option>    
</select>

<select id="s_city">
</select>

<input type="text" id="t_city" style="display:none;">
```

Script

```
function check(s)
{
    document.getElementById('t_city').value ='';
    document.getElementById('s_city').innerHTML='';


   var c= s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
   //Here You Can Start Loading your states with each country
   if(c !="USA")
   {
    document.getElementById('t_city').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('s_city').style.display='none';
   }
  else
   {
    document.getElementById('t_city').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('s_city').style.display='block';
   }
}
```

I Wish This example helped out

Answer (score 0):

Using the DOM/Inner HTML Method you can achieve that.

innerHTML method without JQuery

```
<select id='country_select'>
<div id='container'>
<input ...>
</div>

if (document.getElementById ("country_select").value != "USA")
{
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "<input ...>";
}
else
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "<select ...>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that you will need a drop-down for the state and also a text box. If you prefer to display the drop down first then don't display the text box, or inter change.

Though my solution is pretty similar to Marvan, just take a look a live example here

- [http://jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2MEZ/)

for other reference. If your going to send this along with form you, I guess the name must be same.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a dropdownlist of states and a textbox for other countries.

HTML

```
<select id="cboCountry">
    <!-- <option value="USA">USA</option> -->
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
<select id="cboState">
    <!-- <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option> -->
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtState" style="display:none;" />
```

Javascript

```
$('#cboCountry').change(
    if($('#cboCountry').value() != 'USA'){
        $('#txtState').show();
        $('#cboState').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#txtState').hide();
        $('#cboState').show();
    }
);
```